# Server Side React to HTML

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-dom

How do you configure a node server to host React components/templates and output the HTML as a string after passing in props?

The concept:

```
const React = require('react');
const { renderToStaticMarkup } = require('react-dom/server');

const sayHello = props => (
   return renderToStaticMarkup(<p>Hello, {props.name}!</p>);
)

module.exports = sayHello;
```

This seems like the simplest things to do, yet there's very little documentation to make this work in NodeJS. I've tried many different webpack/babel plugins and node errors as soon as you write jsx, ie: `<p>Hello...</p>`.

Comment: look into nextjs, its best for server side react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import jsx from '../src/app';
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";


function template(reactDom) {
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <title>React App</title>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="app">${reactDom}</div>

            <script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
         </body>
        </html>
    `;
}

app.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
    const reactDom = renderToString(jsx);
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.end(template(reactDom));
});
```

`jsx` is the app file, not the `index.js` file, the `index.js` contain `ReactDom.render`,  which is not what is required.

[`renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

it's worth looking into [`Next.js`](https://nextjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks Jamal, this is the concept I was going for. My intention was to generate HTML from React on the fly without extensive babel/webpack config. So to make it work I also had to add this to the top of my file:

`require('babel-register')({ presets: ['es2015', 'react']});`

And then in the renderToString, I had to do some find and replace:

`const pageHTML = renderToString(template(App)).replace(/&lt;/gi, '<').replace(/&gt;/gi, '>').replace(/&quot;|&amp;quot;/gi, '"');`

Comment: @user1791914 glad it worked, sorry for the `require('babel-register')` I forgot to included.